# Padding Bit Representation with Ones on Right and Left

Tags: c, padding, bit

I've tried searching with Google and reading Wikipedia, but none of them mentions if there is a command to pad a bit sequence with ones on the left/right. For instance, 01000 would become 010001111. I can do this with bit masking but my techniques are rather slow. So what's a standard way of doing this in C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned pad(unsigned pattern, unsigned patternLen,
             unsigned leftBit, unsigned leftBitCnt,
             unsigned rightBit, unsigned rightBitCnt)
{
  unsigned r;
  assert(leftBitCnt < sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT);
  assert(rightBitCnt < sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT);
  assert(patternLen < sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT);
  assert(leftBitCnt + patternLen + rightBitCnt <= sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT);

  r = (leftBit << leftBitCnt) - leftBit;
  r <<= patternLen;
  r |= pattern;
  r <<= rightBitCnt;
  r |= (rightBit << rightBitCnt) - rightBit;

  return r;
}

void printBin(unsigned x)
{
  unsigned i;
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT; i++)
    printf("%u", (x >> (sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT - 1 - i)) & 1);
  printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
  printBin(pad(0x0F0, 12, 0, 2, 0, 2));
  printBin(pad(0x0F0, 12, 0, 2, 1, 2));
  printBin(pad(0x0F0, 12, 1, 2, 0, 2));
  printBin(pad(0x0F0, 12, 1, 2, 1, 2));
  return 0;
}
```

Output ([ideone](http://ideone.com/ocvhz)):

```
00000000000000000000001111000000
00000000000000000000001111000011
00000000000000001100001111000000
00000000000000001100001111000011
```

Answer (score 1):

To pad the value `i` with `n` 1 bits to the right (least significant bits), you can calculate:

```
(i + 1 << n) - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

For both, I will use `x` for the original number and `n` for number of bits to pad.

Right (least-significant) padding:

I believe the fewest operations you can get away with is:

```
(x + 1 << n) - 1
```

How did I get there?  Start with shifting `x` over (`x << n`).  Now its where we want it, but padded with `0`s.  We can get the right number of `1`s with `(1 << n) - 1`.  Now, normally we would bitwise-or them together.  However, since all of the `1`s in one of them lines up with a `0` in the other, we can also add them, which let's us simplify: `(x << n) + (1 << n) - 1 = (x + 1 << n) - 1`.  Keep in mind that `+`/`-` occurs before `<<`/`>>` operations.

Left (most-significant padding):

```
x | -1 << BIT_WIDTH - n
```

First, we use `-1` because it is all ones.  I'm assuming this is signed; if not, use `MAX_INT`, or the relative constant for the type of `x`.  Then, simply shift all of the `1`s over `BIT_WIDTH - n` slots, which leaves us with n `1`s in the correct place.  Here, we should bitwise-or with `x`, because `x` could potentially have `1`s in a position that is supposed to be padded.  Also, because we can't simplify it even if we use addition.